# Can one "miss memories"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

It kinda doesn't make sense to me because it's something that cannot disappear like moments or a person.

[image]

Comment: I suspect that "memories" in this case is being used figuratively. *I miss the good times* or *Those were the days; I miss them.*

Comment: In the same way as 'he savoured the memory' means he savoured that which was remembered (rather than the act of remembering) so 'miss the memory' refers to the thing remembered.

Comment: There are things I can remember remembering, even though I cannot call to mind the actual detailed memories.

Comment: "Nostalgia ain't what it used to be"

Answer (score 1):

This is synecdoche, using a portion of something to refer to the whole. A less metaphorical sentence might be "I miss [the activities that led to those good] memories, man."

If you insist on a literal interpretation, you might miss memories that you no longer have, but remember having. For example, if you can no longer remember how your dead parents smells, but you are nostalgic for the time when you could recall that scent, you might "miss the memory".

Answer (score 0):

If someone has amnesia, alzheimers, brain damage or such like, they could miss memories, but I suspect that in this particular case, the person misses *making* the memories.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, 'miss memories' isn't the correct phrase. It can be 'Lost memories'. BUT, miss/lost memories refer to the result of a memory loss or brain damage. Hence, they cannot be used in sentences.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense. First off _miss_ is a present-tense verb, _lost_ (here) is an adjective or a (passive) past participle. Missing memories is not at all the same as lost memories. And the claim that neither can “be used in sentences” because they’re the result of memory loss or brain damage is… well, quite bizarre, to say the least. Why on earth would the fact that something results from brain damage mean we can’t talk about it? Wouldn’t be many neurologists around if that were true.